# Screen sharing from Mac to Android tablet

Tags: mac, screen-sharing, android

I want to use my Android Pixel tablet as a second screen for my Macbook Air, similar to how users of the app Duet use their iPad as a second screen for the Macbook. Is there any free/inexpensive app that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not in anyway affiliated with the following company / developer but I think [iDisplay](https://getidisplay.com/) might be the solution you're looking for. They have an application for Android as well.

Comment: That's the first app I too thought of

Answer (score 1):

I just bougth iDisplay, it connects to your app via ip/network connectivity. This will require your tablet to be on the same network as your Mac.

Think about it when you're trying to use it at work - if your work has policies on that kind of thing.